# PHP advanced JSON code

Tags: php, json

How can I get to PHP the "1837" from this JSON code? Can someone help me, I don't understand it. :( Because there is more than 1 "countHint" and I can't get the "1837" value.

```
{
   "gd$feedLink":[
      {
         "rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.subscriptions",
         "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/subscriptions?v=2",
         "countHint":68
      },
      {
         "rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.liveevent",
         "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/live/events?v=2",
         "countHint":0
      },
      {
         "rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.favorites",
         "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/favorites?v=2",
         "countHint":795
      },
      {
         "rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.contacts",
         "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/contacts?v=2",
         "countHint":9915
      },
      {
         "rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.inbox",
         "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/inbox?v=2"
      },
      {
         "rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.playlists",
         "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/playlists?v=2"
      },
      {
         "rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.uploads",
         "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/uploads?v=2",
         "countHint":1837
      },
      {
         "rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.newsubscriptionvideos",
         "href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/newsubscriptionvideos?v=2"
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: No, it isn't. But such questions where already answered a few times and it seems like you haven't even used a search engine before posting that question. I guess, that is the reason for the downvotes…

Comment: Stack Overflow rewards the amount of research and showcasing prior attempts in your question. Tutoring pleas and name calling not so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can decode the JSON data into a PHP array or object and then use the normal PHP array functions to filter by a specific value. (The latter was explained often enough on SO).

```
$json = '{ "gd$feedLink":[ … ] }';
$phpArray = json_decode( $json, true );
```

Answer (score 0):

Just like feela described use json_decode here is the full code :D enjoy

```
$json = '{
    "gd$feedLink": [
        {
            "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.subscriptions",
            "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/subscriptions?v=2",
            "countHint": 68
        },
        {
            "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.liveevent",
            "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/live/events?v=2",
            "countHint": 0
        },
        {
            "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.favorites",
            "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/favorites?v=2",
            "countHint": 795
        },
        {
            "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.contacts",
            "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/contacts?v=2",
            "countHint": 9915
        },
        {
            "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.inbox",
            "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/inbox?v=2"
        },
        {
            "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.playlists",
            "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/playlists?v=2"
        },
        {
            "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.uploads",
            "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/uploads?v=2",
            "countHint": 1837
        },
        {
            "rel": "http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.newsubscriptionvideos",
            "href": "http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/pewdiepie/newsubscriptionvideos?v=2"
        }
    ]
}';

$decoded = json_decode($json,true);

foreach ($decoded['gd$feedLink'] as $item  ){
    if( isset($item['countHint']) && $item['countHint']=='1837'){
        echo $item['rel']."<br/>";
        echo $item['href']."<br/>"; 
        echo $item['countHint']."<br/>";

    }

}
```